# My code seems to break in line 2 at int(number), i don’t know why though?

Tags: python

Please help. I have the follow exercise but I can't get my code to work.

---

For every positive total number n you can determine a unique code consisting of two numbers m and p. That works like this:

- Step 1: Write n as a number in the binary system, as a binary number b. See below for explanation.
- Step 2: Write b backwards as a binary number a.
- Step 3: The number m is the number of zeros with number one starting.
- Step 4: You get the number by writing the binary number as a number in the decimal system.

For example, suppose n = 202.

1. Binary you can write that as 1100010.
2. If you write that backwards, you get 01010011.
3. That number starts with 1 times a 0.
4. If you omit that you get 1010011. Write that again in the decimal system and you get 83.

The AB code of 202 is then the pair 1 and 83.
Write a program that takes a number n in the least of standard input. 0 < n < 1000000000 applies.
The program writes two lines to standard output. On the first line is the number m and on the second the number p.

Example:
Input: 202
Output: 1 83

---

```
number = input()
a = f'{​​​​​​int(number):0b}​​​​​​'
a = str(a)
code = []
zeroes = 0
for i in a:
  code.append(i)
code.reverse()
while True:
  if code[0] == "0":
    code.pop(0)
    zeroes = zeroes + 1 
else:
  break 
  x = ''
for i in range(len(code)):
  x = x + code[i]
newnum = int(x ,2)
print(str(zeroes))
print(newnum)
```

Comment: Applying some binary logic all your code could be replaced with `newnum = number >> (number & -number).bit_length() - 1`

Comment: I updated my post, the exercise is more clear now i think.

Comment: You could apply binary AND to count leading zeros: `zeroes = (number & -number).bit_length() - 1` Then you could use binary shift to omit those zeroes: `newnum = number >> zeroes`.

Comment: By the way, pair should be `1` and `101`, `83` is not correct (should not be). `83` is `01010011`, bit's are reversed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but is the fString statement correct? Or should it be like:

> f'int({number}):0b'

Comment: I updated my post, the exercise is more clear now i think.